# xml:space="preserve" effect on space between XML attributes?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, whitespace, w3c

I know that

```
<a xml:space="preserve">
<b></b>
</a>
```

is different than

```
<a xml:space="preserve">
<b>  </b>
</a>
```

---

However, what about

```
<a xml:space="preserve">
<b c='c'></b>
<c   />
</a>
```

and

```
<a xml:space="preserve">
<b     c='c'></b>
<c />
</a>
```

I can't find documentation about how `xml:space="preserve"` affects these cases.

Comment: and what about <a xml:space="preserve"><b></b></a> and <a xml:space="preserve"><b/></a> ?

Comment: White spaces do not make any difference in XML.

Comment: @jdweng then what does xml:space actually do in your opinion?

Comment: For the first case the innertext is different like the different between two string "" (no space) and " " (one space).  The second case there is absolutely no difference.  It is just an extra space between the element name and the first attribute.  It is like putting the attribute on a new line.

Comment: @jdweng Then I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [**`xml:space="preserve"`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space) directive says that space within [*element content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-elemcontent) is significant.<sup>1</sup>

It does not affect [whitespace within start tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-STag), which is significant only to the extent that its presence is needed to separate attributes from themselves and from the name of the element:

> ```
> [40] STag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
> ```

Note that the `S` [production](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-S) *requires* one whitespace character and *allows* multiple:

> ```
> [3] S ::= (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
> ```

---

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> <sub>The default (and only other allowed setting), `xml:space="default"`, allows indentation (pretty-printing) of XML without changing significance.</sub>